# file reading using scanner and string tokenizer and retrieve adjacency list

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Graph1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int linecount = 0, ec = 0;
        int nbin = 0, cbin = 0;
        int[][] data = new int[6][6];
        String e = "e";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        String newfile = sc.nextLine() + ".txt";
        File file = new File(newfile);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while ((scan.hasNext())) {
            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(scan.nextLine());
            if(t.nextToken().equals(e)) {
                ec++;System.out.print("ec.." + ec );
                nbin = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
                cbin = Integer.parseInt(t.nextToken());
                data[nbin][cbin] = 1;
            }
        }
```

my input file is:

```
jjjjjjjjj
e 1 3
e 2 5
e 3 4
e 4 1
e 5 3
```

here adjacency matrix is produced.i had updated the file.i want to convert the file entries into an adjacency list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `data` declaration from

```
 int[][] data = new int[5][5];
```

To

```
int[][] data = new int[6][6];
```

Because, at `cbin=5`

```
  data[nbin][cbin] = 1;// ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
```

Comment: i need to convert this data into adjacency list.do u have any idea?